# Handle multiple exception in Python with only one try - except block

Tags: python-3.x

```
try:
    print(10/0)
    print(10/2)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Hello everyone, with this snippet above. I have an output

```
division by zero
```

I expected the output

```
division by zero
5.0
```

I know that it's the way Python handle exception and there is another way to achieve this is using multiple try - except block. But is there any way can be used with only one try - except block.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is not possible using a single try except block.

Comment: No, exception's interrupt the current flow of execution. How could it know that you want to "go back" to the place where the exception happened. This seems like an X Y problem though. Can you explain a bit more of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: This describes an xy problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: @matt I call function and I don't know exactly where will the error appear, so I need to use try - except to avoid crashing. But I don't want to reuse try - except block.

However, I got your point. We should handle specific error for each exception, if python allow user use a single exception for all, then when the problem happend, we can't know where is the error come from.

Comment: "we can't know where is the error come from" - That's on you. - That's exactly why the try blocks should be as small as possible and as precise as possible (you should `except ZeroDivisionError` and not just `except Exception`!). You could consider using loops or functions to not repeat yourself (note: when you start making bigger projects, don't catch everything as soon as it's raised, consider letting some errors propagate out and catch them later)

Comment: I really appreciate your advice @h4z3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two statements, it isn't really feasible. If you have a lot of statements to manage, then you would use a class.

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, task):
        self._task = task
    def run(self):
        self._task()
```

Then we process each task in a try/except.

```
def process( task ):
    try:
        task.run()
    catch Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Now any task we run we not raise an exception. This is somewhat common in loops where you don't want to crash a program to due unanticipated user input.

```
x = Task( lambda: print(10/0) )
y = Task( lambda: print(10/2) )
process(x)
process(y)
```

That way both x and y will get processed regardless of whether one of them errors. This is a lot of work for 2 inputs, but if you have a lot of tasks. One example is a GUI event loop.

Note this would prevent a task from calling sys.exit() and exiting the program because it raises an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will use it as an reference for my project.